# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5672 out of bounds for length 247 in Java 11

Tags: java, jersey

In deployment with Tomcat Server, there was a run time error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5672 out of bounds for length 247
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$2.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:104)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:102)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:417)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:584)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1629)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:304)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1174)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1396)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1400)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1368)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: @DangNguyen , how it this question related to that, kindly look at the context before mentioning relativity to different questions asking the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

try a more recent version of asm, iirc it's a mismatch between asm and the java version you are using

Comment: Any Suggestions for JDK 11. Which version of "asm" and "Jersey" jars needs to be used.?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem causing this would be lying within your pom file.
Fundamentally , tomcat being an application server bundles its own .jar files that any J2EE application being deployed within it "may need".

In many instances, Tomcat may be having a new version of one of the dependencies, in my view the culprit here looks like asm, and within your dependencies
`mvn dependency:tree` , you could be referencing an older version of asm, albeit not intentionally , it may be good if you could, exclude the dependency from your pom dependencies and try to deploy again.

Option 2:

To assert the analogy of if its the asm or any other dependency, try depoying to another application server like Glassfish or wildfly and note the differences or similarities.

Comment: Any Suggestions for JDK 11. Which version of "asm" and "Jersey" jars needs to be used.?

Comment: Its is not JDK agnostic , rather a contract between the application server  and your application's dependency. JDK has no control over this contract . Its function is to provide a platform for converting your code into byte code.
As I said , you may want to try another application server to rule out the dependency concern I think could be the problem.